# Jquery add class callback

Tags: jquery

I don't know how to do this, when i click on a div, a class is added to an other div, so my problem is how to add event listner to the new added class.

```
$('div.my_class').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).next().addClass('added_class');
});

$('div.added_class').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // some stuff here 
        $(this).prev().removeClass('added_class');
});
```

Comment: There is no callback, nor is there an event handler, as changing the class happens right away, it's completely synchronous, so you don't need an event handler or callback

Comment: can you show your html?

Comment: Oh wait, I think I get it now, you're just asking how to do a delegated event handler in jQuery

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to delegate the event handler. Try `$(document).on('click', 'div.added_class', function () {...});`

Comment: [**Understanding Event Delegation - jQuery Documentation**](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: @JoshCrozier thanks man that's what i'm looking for